# Differentiation with an Indicator function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What would be the derivative of the following expression w.r.t. $\pi_k$

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^K\mathbb{I}[y_n=k]ln(\pi_k)$$

Is it simply, $\frac{N_k}{\pi_k}$ where $N_k=\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb{I}[y_n=k]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I get:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_i} \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^K\mathbb{I}[y_n=k]\ln(\pi_k)
= \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^K\mathbb{I}[y_n=k]\frac{\delta_{ik}}{\pi_k}
= \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\mathbb{I}[y_n=i]}{\pi_i}
= \frac{1}{\pi_i} \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{I}[y_n=i]
$$
Thus, your result was correct.